# How to reach contents of a nested JSON response body in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, frisby.js

I need to automate some API tests with frisby.js, and I'm stuck at accessing to some data which is nested inside JSON response body.

Below is my code

```
var frisby = require('c:/frisby');

frisby.create('Request available Voyages')
    .post('someURL', {
        departureVoyage: {
            from: "500",
            to: "500",
            date: '2017-01-07'}})
    .inspectJSON()
    .afterJSON(function (voyage) {
       console.log(voyage.departureVoyage.voyages);}
```

Below is the output of inspectJSON() function

```
{ type: 'voyageResponseWsDTO',
  departureVoyage:
   { date: '2017-01-07',
     voyages:
      [ { endTime: '22:30',
          quotas:
           [ { id: '8796095719239',
               limit: 66,
               name: 'PROMOTION',
               price: '34',
               priceCurrency: 'USD' },
             { id: '8796095620935',
               limit: 271,
               name: 'ECONOMY',
               price: '51',
               priceCurrency: 'USD' },
             { id: '8796095489863',
               limit: 19,
               name: 'BUSINESS',
               price: '72',
               priceCurrency: 'USD' },
             { id: '8796234721095',
               limit: 0,
               name: 'CAR PROMOTION',
               price: '84',
               priceCurrency: 'USD' },
             { id: '8796095752007',
               limit: 2,
               name: 'VIP',
               price: '800',
               priceCurrency: 'USD' } ],
          time: '20:00',
          vessel:
           { carriesVehicles: true,
             TypeCode: 'FE',
             TypeName: 'Ferry' } } ] } }
```

and below is the output of console.log(voyage.departureVoyage.voyages);

```
[ { endTime: '22:30',
    quotas: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    time: '20:00',
    vessel:
     { carriesVehicles: true,
       TypeCode: 'FE',
       TypeName: 'Ferry' } } ]
```

My problem is, when I try to access content of "quotas" with "`console.log(voyage.departureVoyage.voyages.quotas);`" I get "`undefined`" message.
Do you know a way how can I reach data of this "quotas"? Because I need to reach properties of this "quotas", like id of one them.

Thanks

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`voyage.departureVoyage.voyages` is an array, and quotas is in the first item of that array,

So refer it like below for `quotas` inside it,

```
voyage.departureVoyage.voyages[0].quotas
```

Comment: But when I use 
   "console.log(voyage.departureVoyage.voyages[1]);"
I get "undefined" message back,
and when I use 
    "console.log(voyage.departureVoyage.voyages.results[0]);" this time it gives the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: You can't use `voyage.departureVoyage.voyages.results[0]` as it is undefined. where is your `results` key in the object exactly ? Post the complete object.

Comment: If it is at the same level of `quotas`, you can refer it like `voyage.departureVoyage.voyages[0].results`

Comment: thank you a lot mate!
I used "console.log(voyage.departureVoyage.voyages[0].quotas[0].id);" and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Cool. No problem. Happy coding :)